# Passing encoded variable from php and decoding in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a very ugly piece of code in php that does something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= ($fi_int-1); $i++) {
        $song_uri = urlencode($songs[$i]);

        echo "URI: " . $song_uri . "<br>";
        echo "<li><a href='#' onclick='PlaySong(".$song_uri.")'>" . $songs[$i] . "</li><br>";
    }
```

Now when PlaySong() is being called, this happens:

```
<script>

            function PlaySong(title) {
                title = decodeURIcomponent(title));
                document.getElementById("player").src = "./mp3/" + title;
            }

</script>
```

The current problem is when $songs[$i] is being passed to PlaySong(), it looks like that right away:

```
PlaySong(Name+Of+The+Song+-+Artist+LastName+blah) {
  ...
}
```

So JS obviously has a problem with it. It tries to add things, because there are pluses... Now how can I convert that mess to string right when it comes in? Or is there a better way to do it? I'm sure there is but this ugliness is strictly for me, so I don't care too much about fast performance :)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You `urlencode` the string, so you end up with a urlencoded string. Pluses are spaces in urlencoded strings, so whats wrong with this?

Comment: @tkausl What exactly is wrong is that it doesn't work. My idea, as I described above why it doesn't work is that when js takes over, inside of PlaySong() function parameter list, there is a crap load of mess which says: Take Name add it to Of add that to The add that to Name and so on. So it doesn't matter that I try to decode later, even before that, in the argument part of the function it already gets confused. But maybe I'm wrong. The fact still stays the same - this scheme doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some quotes around the song_uri string. I can't paste code on mobile... but the php should output like this

Onclick="PlaySong ('this+song')"

At the moment you've got it doing

Onclick="PlaySong(this+song)" and the argument isn't being treated as a string

Comment: Inside of my for loop, I put single quotation marks like this: `onclick='PlaySong('".$song_uri."')'` but now the chrome console says this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` near here: `(function(event){PlaySong(
})`

Comment: Ye that won't work because the second single quote is closing the first. I would swap the single quotes arround onclick to double quotes. You'll need to escape these as they're within the echo so will be something like onclick=\"....

Comment: Awesome, with a couple more tweaks I made it work! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ye sorry, I was on my mobile unable to get to a PC so couldn't just paste the code. Glad you got it working :)